# How can I allow traffic only from my load balancer, if the private IP of the load balancer changes all the time?

Tags: security, iptables, load-balancing, rackspace, rackspace-cloud

I'd like to limit (via iptables or otherwise) inbound traffic on 80/443 to traffic coming from my load balancer. I have the public IP (which doesn't change, of course), but the only private IP info I get is a range (I'm using Rackspace's "Cloud Load Balancer"), and I don't want any traffic coming in from anywhere but my own load balancer (otherwise, somebody who knows my server's IP can just create a cloud load balancer and point it to my server). If I use the public IP, won't the TCP handshake cause a lot of latency (vs being able to directly connect from within my data center)? I want to be able to take my servers entirely offline when I have problems or for updates, but without having to mess with low-level networking junk during these problems/updates.

Comment: Can you not set a static private ip address on relevant interface on the load balancer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about filtering on something that does NOT change, like mac address?

http://tecadmin.net/mac-address-filtering-using-iptables

```
Allow Full Access to specific MAC
# iptables -I INPUT -m mac --mac-source 3E:D7:88:A6:66:8E -j ACCEPT

Allow port 80
# iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m mac --mac-source 3E:D7:88:A6:66:8E -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Excellent, +1 - Do you know happen to know how I would get the mac address of a cloud load balancer? Also, does it not seem feasible that the mac address would change, since it's a virtual appliance, vs a dedicated piece of hardware?

Comment: 'arp -a' may reveal the mac address